# Access JSON through variable path in PHP

Tags: php, json

In PHP, how to get a JSON value from a variable path ?

Here is a sample json and a function with 2 params: a json variable, and path split into keys.

```
$myjson = json_decode('{
    "myKey1": {
        "myKey2": {
            "myKey3": {
                "myKey4": "myfinalvalue"
            }
        }
    }
}');

function getJSONValue($myjson, $pathkey) {
    // split path keys by ";"
    $myjson-> ?? $pathkey ??
}

echo getJSONValue($myjson, "myKey1;myKey2;myKey3;myKey4");
// Should display "myfinalvalue"
```

the static equivalent would be to do:

```
$myjson->myKey1->myKey2->myKey3->myKey4;
```

I tried:

```
$myjson->$pathkey
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work...

Comment: You mix `PHP` and `JS`. Your definition of `$myjson` is invalid in PHP.

Comment: json is an encoding/transport format. You don't work with json in PHP. you decode the json to a native PHP structure (e.g. array), and then it's just a normal php structure. `var_dump($result_from_json_decode)` will SHOW you that structure.

Comment: Also, with the way you've defined your PHP `getJSONValue` function, it would only take accept `$myjson` and `myKey1` as arguments. The rest would be ignored.

Comment: yep, my bad, I mix up with JS. I edited the post to stick to a PHP problem

Comment: have you tried doing any coding to solve this problem? btw, you still haven't posted actual PHP code for `$myjson`.

Comment: iterating through an array would be a way... but I was wondering another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your question has nothing to do with JSON. This is how you can get a value from a nested object:

```
function getValue($obj, $path) {
    foreach(explode(';', $path) as $key) {
        $obj = $obj->$key;
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

As for the JSON part, your example is not a valid JSON. It should be like this:

```
$myjson = json_decode('{
    "myKey1": {
        "myKey2": {
            "myKey3": {
                "myKey4": "myfinalvalue"
            }
        }
    }
}');
```

Also, php objects are case-sensitive, if you have `myKey` in the object, it should be `myKey` (and not `mykey`) in the path string.

Comment: true, but JSON format is part of my problem, I have made a shortcut. Your answer fit to my context, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
function getJSONValue($myjson, array $pathkey) {
    foreach($pathkey as $val){
        $myjson = $myjson->{$val};
    }
    return $myjson;
}

$myjson = json_decode('{"myKey1": {"myKey2": {"myKey3": {"myKey4": "myfinalvalue"}}}}');


echo getJSONValue($myjson, ["myKey1","myKey2","myKey3","myKey4"]);
```

live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/1G78Fi

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function getJSONValue() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $json = array_shift($args);
  $key = array_shift($args);
  $value = $json->$key;
  if(is_object($value)) {
    array_unshift($args, $value);
    return call_user_func_array('getJSONValue', $args);
  }
  return $value;
}
```

No error checking.

Comment: thanks Marek, I really like your answer because of the generic way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are mixing PHP and JS. check this out to see how to create a Json string, then getting an onject out of it, and accessing keys:

```
$myjson = json_encode(array(
    'myKey1' => array(
        'mykey2' => array(
            'mykey3' => array(
                'myKey4' => "myfinalvalue"
            )
        )
    )
));

$obj = json_decode($string);


echo $obj->myKey1->mykey2->mykey3->myKey4
// "myfinalvalue"
```

or pasting the json directly:

```
$obj =  json_decode(
    '{
        myKey1: {
            mykey2: {
                mykey3: {
                    myKey4: "myfinalvalue"
                }
            }
        }
    }');

echo $obj->myKey1->mykey2->mykey3->myKey4
// "myfinalvalue"
```

To understand it betterm, read about [**JSON_DECODE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)